# posting list creation in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm creating a sequential document dictionary, where each key is a url and the values are a dictionary with the keys as pagename and value as page text. My algorithm for creating this works, but I wanted to create an inverted index list simultaneously, except this is hard because my sequential document dictionary is being made through multiprocessing. My current code is:

```
sequentialDict[url] = {name : page_text} 
wordSet = set(page_text)
    for w in wordSet:
        try:
            wordDict[w] = wordDict[w].append(url)
        except:
            wordDict[w] = [url]
```

except this is not thread-safe. Is there a way to create my document list and postings list simultaneously like this?

Comment: Please include a bit more code showing how you're currently filling in `wordDict` with multiprocessing. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe `sequentialDict` is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Do include few more lines of code showing the wordDict. Other the code looks fine. Have you thought of leveraging the lucene invertedIndex format (postings list) for your purpose that can be done in parallel?